# Is the critical value the value which is closest to the significance level or the value which is below the significance level?

Tags: statistics, binomial-distribution, hypothesis-testing

Consider the example below which I will use to aid my question:

> X - B(20, 0.2)
>
> **H0:** p = 0.2
>
> **H1:** p ≠ 0.2

Testing at the 10% significance level, the tail is 0.05 at either end.

At the lower end:

> **P(X <= 0)** = 0.0115
>
> **p(X <= 1)** = 0.0692

Since both values are not equal to 0.05, do we take the critical value as the value which has a closer probability to 0.05, which would be 1 in this instance, or do we take the critical value as the value which is less than the significance level?

I've become confused because the mark scheme chooses the critical value as the value [closer to the significance level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiNLH.png) in some questions but in others, it chooses the critical value as the value which is [less than the significance level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbFJa.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an instructive question on two accounts.

**General point**

The questioner has not provided the source material for the confusion. This is why the initial two answers do not actually answer the question.

Since they do not know where the examples and mark schemes have come from, the authors of the previous answers, through no fault of their own, have provided somewhat generic responses.

The key point here is either to include, or reference, all the relevant material. In this case the questioner should have included the whole of each question and the whole of each mark scheme.

**The answer to the question**

The two examples are Questions 6 and 7 of *Mixed Exercise 7* from the *Edexcel AS and A level Mathematics* textbook *Statistics and Mechanics Year 1/AS* (Harry Smith ed., 2017).

Once that has been determined, the confusion is easy to resolve. Here is the text of part (a) of question 6, the questioner’s first example (my italics):

> Find the critical region that would enable the manager to test whether
> or not there is evidence that the probability is different from 0.2.
> *The probability of each tail should be as close to 2.5% as possible*.

The reason the mark scheme for question 6 uses a probability that is closer to 2.5% rather than below, is that the question specifically asks for it. Without that, the lower value would have been used, as in question 7.

In general the critical value is the first value to fall within the critical region, even if it is not the closest to boundary. In cases where the first value outside is significantly closer to the boundary than the first value inside, the question should indicate which to use.

Answer (score 1):

For a two-tailed binomial exact test, the rejection region depends on how you allocate the $\alpha$.  You suggest an equal allocation of $\alpha/2$ to each tail, thus you require the maximum $x_1$ such that $\Pr[X \le x_1 \mid H_0] \le \alpha/2$, and the minimum $x_2$ such that $\Pr[X \ge x_2 \mid H_0] \le \alpha/2$.   For $n = 20$, as you pointed out, $\Pr[X = 0] \approx 0.0115292$ but $\Pr[X \le 1] \approx 0.0691753 > \alpha/2$.  We also have $\Pr[X \ge 8] \approx 0.0321427$, but $\Pr[X \ge 7] \approx 0.0866925 > \alpha/2$.  So the rejection region for an equal-tailed allocation is $$(X = 0) \cup (X \ge 8).$$
What is interesting is that the rejection region $(X = 0) \cup (X \ge 7)$ has an overall Type I error of $0.0982217 < \alpha$, but it isn't equal allocation.  Similarly we could also choose $(x \le 1) \cup (X \ge 9)$ with an overall Type I error $0.0791571$ but again this is unequal allocation of $\alpha$ to the tails.

Answer (score 1):

To understand where the reject set is, you ca do a drawing of your binomial (I did not include the x-values over 11 because they are all almost zero in probability)

[image]

and you can easy see where the rejection interval is...you have a probability of $1.2\%$ on the left and a probability of $3.2\%$ on the right. That is why because usually you are requested to find an interval with same probability tails. If you include $X=1$ or (latin, AUT) $X=7$ your probability will exceed the fixed $5\%$ in one of the two tails